# How to merge 2 activerecord records together and be left with 1? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 apples:

```
{
 id: 1,
 rotten: true,
 branch_on_tree: nil,
 type: "red delicious"
},
{
 id: 2,
 rotten: nil,
 branch_on_tree: 5,
 type: "red delicious"
}
```

They are duplicate apples for red delicious. How do I merge the records together and then delete the one with missing data? Is there a convenient way to do this?

Note: There might be like 10 duplicates. I don't want any null values in my final record. Non-null values take precedence.

Comment: Is `type` always has some value?

Comment: Also,you want a single record or multiple records that serve your purpose?

Comment: I want to be left with a single record, with all duplicates (coiuld be 10) deleted.

Comment: What if there are multiple records that matching your purpose?

Comment: type always ahs some value

Comment: I want a final record with as much information as possible and as few nil values as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very convinient way but it will work

assuming apples is an array:

```
[
  {
   id: 1,
   rotten: true,
   branch_on_tree: nil,
   type: "red delicious"
  },
  # ...
]
```

that can come from:

```
apples = Apple.where(type: "red delicious")
apples_attrs = apples.map(&:attributes)
```

Then,

```
apple_attrs = apples_attrs.reduce do |apple, next_apple| 
                apple.merge(next_apple) do |_, old_value, new_value| 
                  old_value || new_value
                end
              end


apples.destroy_all
Apple.create(apple_attrs)
```

You might want to check this guide https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `type` always has some value, you can use `DISTINCT` with `where` clause. The below should work

```
Apple.where('rotten IS NOT NULL AND branch_on_tree IS NOT NULL').select('DISTINCT ON (type) rotten,branch_on_tree,type').take
```